# Checking an empty tag in POST -field by Javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

**How can you check an empty tag -field by Javascript like in asking questions at SO?**

I would not like to pass the user to send a question without specifying the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start you off, in your page:

```
function validateForm()
{
    var tags = document.getElementById('tags').value;
    if(tags == '' || tags == null) {
        alert('Please enter one or more tags');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

<form method="post" onsubmit="javascript:validateForm()">
<input type="text" id="tags" name="tags"/>
<input type="submit" value="Post your question"/>
</form>
```

In your PHP script:

```
if(isset($_POST['tags']) && !empty($_POST['tags'])) {
    $tags = $_POST['tags'];
}
```

Comment: So the first JS code should be attached to the action of the send button in PHP. Then, I need to put your first code the JS file which I then source at index.php.

Comment: @Masi - That sounds about right. Note the 'return false' in the JS code above, that will prevent the form from submitting.

Comment: My code puts the question to my database although no tag given. I do get the alert. My code is this http://dpaste.com/83449/ **Do you see the problem?**